# verify rtsp capabilities

Tags: selenium, load-testing, jmeter, rtsp

I need to load test a site that serves up flash video via RTSP.

I've looked at JMeter & Selenium and do not see any support for RTSP.

Are there any testing tools that support RTSP load testing?

Answer (score 0):

If you can find a .NET library that allows you to make RTSP calls, you can override a Visual Studio web test to make RTSP calls instead of http. That will allow you to make load tests for RTSP.

Use 2010 if you can.

Answer (score 0):

My library has a RtspClient which you can use for this:

http://net7mma.codeplex.com/

Check out the CodeProject article @ http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/507218/Managed-Media-Aggregation-using-Rtsp-and-Rtp

If you need anything else let me know!